# Save LocaTime via SpringData to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, jodatime

I try to save a LocalTime (joda) field to the MongoDB with SpringData using spring-boot-starter-parent (org.springframework.boot 1.2.3.RELEASE) and get a StackOverflowError.

The StackOverflowError is in BeanWrapper in the method

```
public <S> S getProperty(PersistentProperty<?> property, Class<? extends S> type)
```

Stacktrace:

```
http-nio-8080-exec-2@5509 daemon, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
  at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BeanWrapper.getProperty(BeanWrapper.java:120)
  at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BeanWrapper.getProperty(BeanWrapper.java:100)
  at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:419)
  at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:412)
  at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:307)
  at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:412)
  at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:511)
  at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:424)
  at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:412)
  at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:307)
  at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:412)
  at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:511)
  at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:424)
  at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:412)
  at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:307)...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding these two Converters to the CustomConversions fix the problem.

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "databasename";
    }

    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new MongoClient("localhost");
    }

    @Override
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
        converters.add(new LocalTimeToStringConverter());
        converters.add(new StringToLocalTimeConverter());
        return new CustomConversions(converters);
    }

}

public class LocalTimeToStringConverter implements Converter<LocalTime, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(LocalTime localTime) {
        return localTime.toString();
    }
}



public class StringToLocalTimeConverter implements Converter<String, LocalTime> {
    @Override
    public LocalTime convert(String s) {
        return LocalTime.parse(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: now all the String are going to be converted to LocalTime, How do i go around this?

Comment: @user1955934 The strings should only be converted to LocalTime if the field type of the class is LocalTime